# try and except not working

Tags: python

Hi i have the following code. When i run getDetails function the try:
does work but the exception is not displaying properly.

```
data_dict = {}
dict_list = []
def createNameDict(filename):
  path = "C:\Users\user\Desktop"
  basename = "ParkingData_Part2.txt"
  filename = path + "//" + basename
  file = open(filename)
  contents = file.read()
  print contents,"\n"


  data_list = [lines.split(",") for lines in contents.split("\n")]



  for line in data_list:
    regNumber = line[0]
    details = (line[1],line[2],line[3])

    data_dict[regNumber] = details
  print data_dict,"\n"
  print data_dict.items(),"\n"

def getDetails(regNumber):
  #if regNumber in data_dict: 
    try:
      if regNumber in data_dict:
        print data_dict[regNumber]

        #print data_dict.get(regNumber)
    except:
      printNow(regNumber, "not in dictionary")
    return
def addRegistration(regNumber, details):
  try:
     data_dict[regNumber] = details


  except:
    print regNumber, "Key Already exist"

 #data_dict.update({regNumber:(details)})
  return data_dict
```

The output I have is:

```
======= Loading Progam =======
>>> createNameDict("C:\Users\user\Desktop//ParkingData_Part2.txt")
EDF768, Bill Meyer, 2456, Vet_Parking
TY5678, Jane Miller, 8987, AgHort_Parking
GEF123, Jill Black, 3456, Creche_Parking
ABC234, Fred Greenside, 2345, AgHort_Parking
GH7682, Clara Hill, 7689, AgHort_Parking
JU9807, Jacky Blair, 7867, Vet_Parking
KLOI98, Martha Miller, 4563, Vet_Parking
ADF645, Cloe Freckle, 6789, Vet_Parking
DF7800, Jacko Frizzle, 4532, Creche_Parking
WER546, Olga Grey, 9898, Creche_Parking
HUY768, Wilbur Matty, 8912, Creche_Parking 

{'HUY768': (' Wilbur Matty', ' 8912', ' Creche_Parking'), 'GH7682': (' Clara Hill', ' 7689', ' AgHort_Parking'), 'GEF123': (' Jill Black', ' 3456', ' Creche_Parking'), 'WER546': (' Olga Grey', ' 9898', ' Creche_Parking'), 'TY5678': (' Jane Miller', ' 8987', ' AgHort_Parking'), 'ABC234': (' Fred Greenside', ' 2345', ' AgHort_Parking'), 'KLOI98': (' Martha Miller', ' 4563', ' Vet_Parking'), 'EDF768': (' Bill Meyer', ' 2456', ' Vet_Parking'), 'JU9807': (' Jacky Blair', ' 7867', ' Vet_Parking'), 'DF7800': (' Jacko Frizzle', ' 4532', ' Creche_Parking'), 'ADF645': (' Cloe Freckle', ' 6789', ' Vet_Parking')} 

[('HUY768', (' Wilbur Matty', ' 8912', ' Creche_Parking')), ('GH7682', (' Clara Hill', ' 7689', ' AgHort_Parking')), ('GEF123', (' Jill Black', ' 3456', ' Creche_Parking')), ('WER546', (' Olga Grey', ' 9898', ' Creche_Parking')), ('TY5678', (' Jane Miller', ' 8987', ' AgHort_Parking')), ('ABC234', (' Fred Greenside', ' 2345', ' AgHort_Parking')), ('KLOI98', (' Martha Miller', ' 4563', ' Vet_Parking')), ('EDF768', (' Bill Meyer', ' 2456', ' Vet_Parking')), ('JU9807', (' Jacky Blair', ' 7867', ' Vet_Parking')), ('DF7800', (' Jacko Frizzle', ' 4532', ' Creche_Parking')), ('ADF645', (' Cloe Freckle', ' 6789', ' Vet_Parking'))] 

>>> getDetails("GFT245")

>>> getDetails("HUY768")

(' Wilbur Matty', ' 8912', ' Creche_Parking')
>>> getDetails("JU9807")

(' Jacky Blair', ' 7867', ' Vet_Parking')

>>> getDetails("GH7682")

(' Clara Hill', ' 7689', ' AgHort_Parking')
>>>
```

If GFT245 is not in dictionary it should show 
GFT245 not in dictionary
but its not coming that way when i execute the program

Comment: I don't see a `printNow()` function defined in your code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is located here:

```
if regNumber in data_dict:
    print data_dict[regNumber]
```

As you are asking whether `regNumber` is or is not present in the dictionary the exception will never be raised due to the fact that in case `regNumber` is not present you will not try to index it, thus not raising the `KeyError` exception.

If you want the exception to be raised then just do:

```
print data_dict[regNumber]
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `getDetails` function the `except` section will never fire as you explicitly check if the key is in the dictionary before you access it, you would want to re-write it either as

```
if key in dict:
    # The key exists and do something
else:
    # The key doesn't exist, notify the user
```

or

```
try:
    print dict[key]
except KeyError:
    # The key doesn't exist, notify the user
```

I prefer the style of the first as exceptions are expensive, of course if you know that you will only have a small number of keys that do not exist in the dictionary and would cause the exception, then you could optimize the second way.

And your `addRegistration` function should be re-written to test if the key exists already and notify the user, else add the data, as it will not warn you or raise an exception if the key already exists, it will just update/replace the data for that key.

Answer (score 1):

```
if regNumber in data_dict:
  print data_dict[regNumber]
```

You have a conditional before accessing `data_dict`. If `regNumber` is not in `dict` then it will not try to access it. Hence no exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

```
def getDetails(regNumber):
  #if regNumber in data_dict: 
    try:
      if regNumber in data_dict:
        print data_dict[regNumber]

        #print data_dict.get(regNumber)
    except:
      printNow(regNumber, "not in dictionary")
    return
```

Nothing in that `try` block is actually *failing.*

Why? Because of the `if regNumber in data_dict` test. If the code is not in the dictionary, it will never attempt to look it up.

Perhaps you meant something like:

```
def getDetails(regNumber):
    if regNumber in data_dict:
        print data_dict[regNumber]
    else:
        printNow(regNumber, "not in dictionary")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
try:
  if regNumber in data_dict:
    print data_dict[regNumber]

    #print data_dict.get(regNumber)
except:
  printNow(regNumber, "not in dictionary")
```

if `regNumber` is not in `data_dict`, no exception occures. Change it to:

```
try:
    print data_dict[regNumber]
except:
  printNow(regNumber, "not in dictionary")
```